# W3 Css validator errors on -moz and -webkit

Tags: css, w3c-validation

I trying to validate my CSS in Level 3 on jigsaw.w3.org.
But I get many error messages for properties which started with -moz or -webkit or -o and ...

What should I do ?

Comment: There is little benefit to trying to validate your CSS. HTML validation is a nice tool however and will save you lots of headaches.

Comment: How is this question too localized? Nearly everybody trying to validate their CSS has the same problem! (*trying to find 2 warnings in between 80 warnings nobody cares, courtesy of the developers of Jigsaw*)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shows you invalid because those properties are proprietary and are not accepted by w3.org

And hence it throws you error messages for those properties, so if you want to validate it completely, you need to use properties which are accepted by w3.org

Or else you can also select an alternate option here

[image: W3c Validator More Options]

Answer (score 3):

Ignore them. Either that or don't use vendor extensions and wait for everyone to catch up with the standards.

Comment: Yep, ignore them. The use of vendor prefixes is **encouraged** by the CSS Working Group when you want to use "new" properties. Beware that their syntax may change on their way to RECommendation status (it did for linear gradients and flexbox, more than once) and you're fine. Still better than old IE behavior (pun intended) not using those prefixes...

Answer (score 1):

Click on “More Options” in the user interface at http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ and the select “Warnings” in the “Vendor Extensions” dropdown. The extensions will still be errors as far as CSS specs are concerned, but messages about them will be shown as warnings, and you can focus on “real” errors better.